# Is it possible to stop CASE if the condition is true, if there is multiple data connected to one ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an evaluation, and I have encountered a problem which I have been trying to solve for days.
When selecting from the table, I want to display if the ID of a different table (table2) is connected to the ID of the main table(table1). However, table1 has several IDs connected from table2. I just want to check, if the ID '9' is connected and I want the query to print 'Yes' and after that I don't want it to check that ID from table1 anymore. My problem is, that I get 'Yes' printed, but after that I also get 'No' printed with the same data because it finds different IDs than '9' too (of course).
I was able to only display 'No' once if the entry from table1 has several entries connected from table2 that are not '9' by using SELECT DISTINCT.
But if an entry has the ID '9' connected from table2, and several others as well, I only need it to display 'Yes' and stop looking at the other entries.

I tried doing it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            table1_ID AS [Number]
          , table1_description AS [Description]
          , CASE WHEN table3_isRelevant = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [IsRelevant]
    , CASE WHEN table2_ID = 9 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Is '9' connected?]

FROM table1

LEFT JOIN
        table3 ON table3_ID = table1_table3_id

INNER JOIN 
        table2 ON table3_ID = table2_table3_ID
```

Normally if you're using CASE it should stop executing if the case is true, according to the documentation of SQL Server, but I probably have a logical error.

I would be very happy about any help.

Comment: Please show us your entire query.

Comment: Your code is ok and won't return `FALSE` unless you wrote something else you didn't provide in your question.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: What happens when you change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` @mekol? Also could you please provide sample data

Comment: I get the same amount of entries with INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN

Comment: Are you sure that `INNER JOIN table2 ON table3_ID = table2_table3_ID` is correct? This might remove some of the NULLed rows from the Outer Join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to just use `exists`.  This is a little complicated because of the nested hierarchy, but it looks like:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM table3 t3
                          WHERE t3.table3_ID = t1.table1_table3_id AND
                                t3.table3_isRelevant = 1
                         )
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) as IsRelevent,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM table2 t2 JOIN
                               table3 t3
                               ON t3.table3_ID = t2.table2_table3_ID
                          WHERE t3.table3_ID = t1.table1_table3_id AND
                                t2.table2_ID = 9
                         )
             THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
        END) AS Is_9_connected
FROM table1;
```

The `SELECT DISTINCT` should not be necessary -- unless you have duplicates in `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JOIN, you can use [EXISTS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) function

```sql
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 where table2.id = table1.id)
```

or you can use exists with a CASE WHEN

```sql
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 where table2.id = table1.id) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as IsRelevant
```

You are not interested in the data from table2 and table3. So the query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    table1_ID AS [Number]
  , table1_description AS [Description]
  , (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table3 where table3.id = table1.id) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as AS [IsRelevant]
, (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 where table2.id = table1.id) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) as AS [Is '9' connected?]
FROM table1
```

Comment: I get the same amount of entries with this solution as with mine.

Comment: did you remove the join with table2? could you create sqlfiddle with example schema?

Comment: take a look at the solution code I've pasted, there will be just a single row result for each row from table1

Answer (score 0):

You are only interested in table2 record with table_id=9, so add this criteria to your join and make the join a left join instead of an inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            table1_ID AS [Number]
          , table1_description AS [Description]
          , CASE WHEN table3_isRelevant = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [IsRelevant]
    , CASE WHEN table2_ID = 9 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Is '9' connected?]
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table3_ID = table1_table3_id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table3_ID = table2_table3_ID AND table2_ID = 9
```

This way table2_id will have value 9 if it is related or null otherwise.

Comment: The problem is, that I also need to display if it doesn't have 9 related to it. I still need those entries as well. But if one entry has 9, and also for example 6, I get a Yes and a No for the same entry and I only want a Yes. But if there is an entry without any 9, I need the No.

Comment: it will as it is a left join so you will always have all records from table1. You are not selecting any information from table2 or table3, only the fact there is a related record or not.

Comment: Thank you! If I comment out the row [Is '9' connected?] and execute the query, I get 56321 entries. However if I use your solution, I get 52000 and if I delete the distinct I get 56390. I looked at the entries and I realized that sometimes the 'Yes' entries are double because they have 2 times '9' added to them. Is there a way to only blend out those duplicates?

Comment: if the left joins (with table2 or table3) can result in multiple lines and you only want one line per table1 row than I suggest to look at the answer of @lukaszberwid.